# SQL Server Entity Framework Insert Not Working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First and SQL Server in my application.
In one place of my code, i tried to simply insert data into the database.
I've got collection of objects like

```
public class DrivingStatistic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public BLL.Consts.DrivingStatisticType Type { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I add it to my object set by simply:

```
foreach(var entity in data)
    _objectSet.Add(entity);
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Everything works fine on my local database, but on a remote server, nothing happens. Almost nothing.

I used SQL Server Profiler and saw, that insert command was created and executed correctly, here it is

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[DrivingStatistics]([CarId], [DateFrom], 
  [DateTo], [Type], [Value])
  VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
  SELECT [Id]
  FROM [dbo].[DrivingStatistics]
  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int,@1 
  datetime2(7),@2 datetime2(7),@3 int,@4 float',@0=1000,@1='2017-08-25 
  07:00:00',@2='2017-08-25 08:00:00',@3=4,@4=0
```

Identity in my table was incremented, but no row was inserted.
I invoked this SQL command manually via Microsoft SQL Management Studio, and everything was successfully committed to Db, but Id was a bigger number than expected, that's I know, that Identity was previously incremented.

Of course, there is no problem with inserting other entities in other parts of the code.

If anyone has seen such issue before, please advise me what could cause this problem.

Any help would be very appreciated :)

EDIT:

- CarId is the foreign key and it is the only one dependency in this table.
- DrivingStatisticType is an enum.
- EntityFramework didn't throw any exception
- Entity Framework is **not trying** to reinsert those rows.
- There is nothing in SQL Server Log about those inserts

Comment: The big increment of the Identity could be a hint to transaction or deadlock problems in the database. When being succesful through the Management Studio, did you profile the db as well? Was the Request succesful at the first try or are there any retry attempts? Did the Entity Framework or the SQL client throw any exception?

Comment: Did you look into the event viewer of the db server? Maybe you can find some hints there.

Comment: Have you tried inserting just one record rather than a collection and are the `Car` and `DrivingStatisicType` properties populated and inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I make it to work by changing

```
foreach(var entity in data)
    _objectSet.Add(entity);
unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

to

```
foreach(var entity in data)
{
    _objectSet.Add(entity);
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

But if anyone knows why in some situation it is not possible to add multiple rows and commit them together, please tell me.
I'm really curious what Was going about here.

Comment: Try with _objectSet.AddRange(data) so you don't need foreach.